# extend wordpress core class in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, class, extend

I am trying to extend a wordpress core class inside my theme's functions.php, & the class I am trying to extend is `WP_Customize_Image_Control` from class `wp-customize-control.php` in wp-includes.

It already extends "WP_Customize_Upload_Control".

I would like to allow the .svg mime-type to be uploaded within the theme customizer.

in my theme's functions.php I am adding these lines:

```
class WP_Customize_Image_Control_SVG extends WP_Customize_Image_Control {
      public $extensions = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg' );
};
```

but sadly this breaks everything.

Any help, hints or tips appreciated.

Comment: You might get some help with this if you describe more details about the error you experience. "This breaks everything" is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

```
/* Extend the Image Control */

class WP_Customize_Image_Control_SVG extends WP_Customize_Image_Control
{
        public function __construct( $manager, $id, $args = array() )
       {
                parent::__construct( $manager, $id, $args );
                $this->remove_tab('uploaded');
                $this->extensions = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg' );
        }
}
```

This goes inside your "customize_register" action

Just make sure you're registering this one instead of the normal image control.